# Selenium Expected Conditions - waiting for an xpath to become available - I dont know how to type it in my code

Tags: python, selenium, expected-condition

I'm Scott, still somewhat new to python, still trying to figure out how it all works...LOL

I have a script that logs into a website for work, does some clicking on a few objects, and then pulls a report based on those settings that were clicked

the problem I am having is that sometimes the server is busy, so things take different amounts of time to appear... some items are not clickable until drop down menus have been activated...etc
so I need the script to wait for the xpath of each object to become available

I dont understand the explicit wait usage

currently code is ***UGLY*** with my bad usage of time.sleep and other various things..

Code Included below...but heres an example of what I need it to wait for
I need to Insert Explicit waits that will wait for the element to become available

Thanks ahead of time for all your help
I've solved quite a few of my other issues in the script with the help of this forum

```
#Close City Arrow
print('Close City')
loc_arrow2 = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rddlLocation_Arrow"]'))
loc_arrow2.click()

time.sleep(2)

#Category Button
print ('Category Button')
CategoryRadioBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('rbnSearchCategory')
CategoryRadioBtn.click()
WebDriverWait(browser,20)

time.sleep(2)

#L1 Set to 3d_blah_blah_blah
print('L1 Set to 3d_blah_blah_blah')

loc_L1 = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctlCategorySelect1_ddlCategory1_Arrow"]'))
loc_L1.click()


time.sleep(2)

loc_L2 = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctlCategorySelect1_ddlCategory1_Input"]'))
loc_L2.clear()
loc_L2.send_keys('3')
loc_L2.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take the below line as sample to explain the EC (Expected Condition).

```
loc_L1 = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctlCategorySelect1_ddlCategory1_Arrow"]'))
```

You have to add below imports to work with Explicit wait using EC.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And here how you have to write the explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait(driver,waitTimeInSec).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.strategy,"xpath_goes_here")))
# Below is the example
loc_L1 = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctlCategorySelect1_ddlCategory1_Arrow"]')))
 # if you want to wait for the element to be clickable then use below.
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctlCategorySelect1_ddlCategory1_Arrow"]')))
```

In case you get the `ElementNotInteractable` exception, then use js click as shown below.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",loc_L1)
```

Comment: so I already had the "from selenium" stuff
when I write it in to fit it then gives me an error about syntax of my next section
''''

if clist == ('Boston'):
    checkbox = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rddlLocation_i1_chkLocationName"]'))
elif clist == ('Broklyn'):
    checkbox = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rddlLocation_i2_chkLocationName"]'))
elif clist == ('Chicago'):
    checkbox = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rddlLocation_i3_chkLocationName"]'))

''''

Comment: ok... may have found the issue...

May just be missing a ) at the end of your example...

Comment: Are you good now?

Comment: ok further review.. problem still exits

Comment: basically, it has to open a dropdown menu, and wait for the dropdown to populate, then click the xpath
If I do the time.sleep(), it does just fine with that
otherwise I get an element not interactable with trying to use the webdriverwait command

Comment: in short... I think the explicit wait is seeing the element appear in the web page, but tries to click on it before it is actually clickable...

how do I get it to wait for it to actually be clickable?

Comment: You can wait for `element_to_be_clickable`, updated the answer. Check and let me know.

Comment: That sort of works


works on some elements, but not others... 

the only thing I can figure, is that some items are already there and available, but changing some things makes them disappear for a split second, but the script has already counted it as there, so it tries to click it while its gone for that split second...
I'd like to find a solution that that problem... but for now it works on most things, and I just added a time.sleep(0.5) for those few that it failed on and it seems to solve teh issue the ugly way